# How to check if data exits in a textfile and if it does it must not save the same data and show a message saying data already exists

Tags: delphi

```
Var
MyFile : Textfile;
shine: String;
Begin
AssignFile(myfile, 'Username.txt');
Reset ( myFile);
 While not EOF(myFile) do
If sLine = edtEnterUser.Text then
Begin
ShowMessage ('Username already exists')
Begin
ReadLn(myFile,sLine);
end
else
Append(myFile);
CloseFile(myFile);
```

Comment: The code you've supplied does not compile. Please edit it in Delphi until it compiles and then re-post the question.

Answer (score 0):

TStringList(Classes) is simpler

```
var
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.LoadFromFile('Username.txt');
    if sl.IndexOf(edtEnterUser.Text) > -1 then
      ShowMessage ('Username already exists');
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: And not only simpler: It is safer, you get Unicode support, etc.

Comment: But I would use this one-liner instead: `IndexText(UserName, TFile.ReadAllLines(FileName)) <> -1` (uses `IOUtils, StrUtils`). (Or `IndexStr` if you want case sensitivity.)

Comment: Can you please explain what you just did

Comment: It's works perfectly but a bit confused

Comment: Can you please explain what you just did and why, the code works perfectly but I'm just confused

Comment: How do you make it not save the same thing then

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add some explanation for OP's questions regarding @Para's answer.

You can create a TStringList class, make it load any file with encoding if required and manipulate it then save it again. Explination:

```pascal
var
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create; // Create the stringlist
  try // Run the code inside a try block so that if an exception gets thrown it will still free the stringlist to prevent a memory leak.
    sl.LoadFromFile('Username.txt', TEncoding.UTF8); // Load the text inside the file.
    if sl.IndexOf(edtEnterUser.Text) > -1 then // If the index is greater than -1 then it exists however if it's -1 then it doesnt exist
      ShowMessage ('Username already exists')
    else
    begin
      sl.add(edtEnterUser.Text); // If it doesnt exist then add it.
      sl.SaveToFile('Username.txt', TEncoding.UTF8); // save to the file.
    end;
  finally
    sl.Free; // Lastly free the stringlist from memory. This code will run regardless if there are errors.
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Do you see the `edit` button beneath @Para's post? If you do, you could have added the comments to that post instead of writing a new but same answer. You need 2000 reps for immediate visibility of your edits to other people's posts, but with your reps, you should be able to suggest edits, which then will be confirmed by somebody else.

Comment: Sorry but how do you make it not save the data if there is the same data already in the text file

Comment: @TomBrunberg My first thought was to use the edit button however I'm greeted with a "Suggested edit queue is full". The reason I did it like this is because I know how frustrating it is to be provided code but have no idea how it works.

Comment: @Henry Use the if - else statement in the code I showed in the answer. I provided comments in everything.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown does not compile, for several reasons.

In any case, to do what you want, simply call `ReadLn()` in a loop, comparing what was read, and if you detect the string you are looking for then set a `Boolean` and exit the loop.  Then check the `Boolean` after the loop is finished.  For example:

```
var
  MyFile: TextFile;
  sUser, sLine: String;
  bFound: Boolean;
begin
  sUser := edtEnterUser.Text;
  AssignFile(MyFile, 'Username.txt');
  Reset(MyFile);
  bFound := False;
  while not EOF(MyFile) do
  begin
    ReadLn(MyFile, sLine);
    if sLine = sUser then
    begin
      bFound := True;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
  if bFound then begin
    ShowMessage('Username already exists');
  end else
  begin
    CloseFile(MyFile);
    Append(MyFile);
    WriteLn(MyFile, sUser);
  end;
  CloseFile(MyFile);
end;
```